# style of a web page in a disordered way

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying with this html page formating for quiete a long time .I want to see these  in the centre of the screen with a nice beautiful way.Any help is appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/bce9LfLL/
My code is
css

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: tahoma;
}
body {
    padding: 30px;
}
#fileid{
width:10%;
height:15%;
}
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #ededed;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
input[type='file'] {
    width:400px;
    height:25px;
    opacity:0
}
#val {
    width: 400px;
    height:25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-indent: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
#button {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 90px;
    background-color: purple;
    height:25px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height:25px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms all;
    -moz-transition: 500ms all;
    transition: 500ms all;
}

#button:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}


body {
    background-color: linen;
}

div{
    color: maroon;
    margin-left: 40px;
    font-size:100%;
} 
#sid{
    color: maroon;
    margin-left: 40px;
    font-size:100%;
}
```

html

```
<div align="center">
<b>Model</b><select id="sid">
<option >Average</option>
<option>Sum</option>
<option>Highest</option>
</select><br>
<div id="fileip">
    <input type='file'> <span id='val'></span>
 <span id='button'>Select File</span>
 </input>
 </div>
<input type="submit" value="run"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Display"><br>
</div>
```

and
javascript

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
})

$("input[type='file']").change(function () {
    $('#val').text(this.value.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''))
})
```

the page should looks like
[image]

Comment: it's very unclear what you want. Please do some scratch, share a pic of what you want.

Comment: mutliple declaration of div style in your CSS make trouble

Comment: @scoolinico so should i delete one div

Comment: @scoolnico  so now the model and input tab gets merged

Comment: Don't give specific styles to your div. Create a class and define style for it. `<div class="style-for-this-block">....</div>`

Comment: @scoolnico i have done as you said but now the select file goes on the top right

Comment: Begin with this layout, and ajust it in function: http://jsfiddle.net/bce9LfLL/36/

Comment: @scoolnico thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to center off the top of my head. First, fix the width and set the margin:0 auto; On the element you wish to center. The second is to put position:relative; left: calc(50% - YOURELEMENTWIDTH);

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<label>` tag.

```html
<body>
    <label for="model">Model</label>
<select id="model">
  <option>Average</option>
  <option>Sum</option>
  <option>Highest</option>
  
</select>
</body>
```

Comment: I meant mention the problem